# Using property for slow methods with Python

Tags: python, properties

What is the preffered method for dealing with attributes in a class that load via a slow method?

In my particular case, I have a `profile` attribute that is populated from a web page using the `requests` library. Depending on the end-user's connection, this can take a few seconds. Here are the two ways I've come up with for portraying this attribute to the end-user:

The load() way:

```
usr = User('username')
usr.profile.load()
name = usr.profile.name
```

The backend:

```
class User:
    username = ''

    profile = None

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.profile = Profile(self.username)

class Profile:
    def load(self):
        # Load the profile here
```

The property way:

```
usr = User('username')
name = usr.profile.name
```

The backend:

```
class User:
    username = ''

    _profile = None

    @property
    def profile(self):
        if not self._profile:
            self._profile = Profile(self.username)
            self._profile.load()

        return self._profile

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

class Profile:
    def load(self):
        # Load the profile here
```

Off the top of my head, the pro's for the property way is it doesn't involve the end-user to know about the load() function and it saves space. The cons are that it's unexpectedly slow for an attribute reference and that it is possible for it to throw an exception during the load() process.

That being said, which is the most Pythonic way to go about this?

Comment: There is no more Pythonic method; it is a trade-off. You as a developer have to make the choice here based on the use-cases and the prevalence of exceptions.

Comment: And besides, what point is there in accessing the `.profile` attribute if not to look up information about that object? If *all* access to `.profile` info is going to require a `.load()` call, then just accessing `.profile` itself is that conscious step to request the data to be loaded.

Comment: That was exactly my line of thinking, I've just never ran into this conundrum before and wanted to make make sure I was approaching this correctly.